# How to send attachments in mail using amazon ses in grails

Tags: email, grails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I'm using

```
Message message = new Message(subject, body)
amazonWebService.ses.sendEmail new SendEmailRequest(source, destination, message)
```

to send emails from my grails application

https://github.com/agorapulse/grails-aws-sdk/blob/master/src/docs/guide/amazonWebService/ses.gdoc

how can I add attachments to the mails and send

Answer (score 0):

It looks like sendEmail takes a **Message** that only allows a subject and a body.  However, you can use [sendRawEmail](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-email-raw.html) instead.  In that case you can add an attachment, but first you have to craft a  mime message to pass to sendRawEmail.  The linked [example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-email-raw.html) shows formatting the mime message with the JavaMail library.    Once you have this mime message you can use sendRawEmail to send the message.

Depending on your situation, you can also use any mail library that supports sending via SMTP and simply treat amazon SES like any other SMTP server.  That may make dealing with attachments easier depending on the library's features.